# Input pup up box with validation in Python using PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a python script which takes the order number as input and the output would be cost of the item, tax & total. Also the address where item has been shipped.
In this program, I have the following piece of code to take the input

```
Oname = '1'  #something that doesn't validate
while True:
    Oname = input("Please enter the Order number: ").upper() #ask for order number
    if not re.match(r"\b[A-Z]{2}[-][0-9]{6}\b", Oname): #check if the Order number is in the right format
        print ("Error! Please enter Order in format 'RS-XXXXXX'") #if the Order number is not in the right format, keep asking
    else:
        break
```

This is working perfectly. However, I want to do this with a pop-up input box (with pyQT4) instead of a command line (I share this with others & they prefer a pup-up box than a command line).
Also, I need a cancel button on the pup-up window & if the user clicks it (the user may have changed his mind & not want to run the program), the python script should stop.

The above two items are absolutely necessary.
Another item on the wish list is, there should be a check box next to entry field called "is this a gift item". If the user checks this box, only the message saying "the item has been shipped to xxxxx address" should be printed. The part of the code where the price is calculated need not be run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have PyQt5.
Try it:

```
import sys 
#from PyQt4.QtCore    import *
#from PyQt4.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Demo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.label = QLabel("Please enter Order in format `RS-XXXXXX`:", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.chBox = QCheckBox("<-is this a gift item")

        self.lineEdit= QLineEdit()

        # a cancel button
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

        self.lineEdit.setToolTip("press RETURN to check")
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(""" QLineEdit {border: None;
                                                   font-size: 14px;} """)
        # lineEdit with validation                                              
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask('AA-999999')    
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda : self.findText(self.lineEdit.text()))

        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()
        self.button = QPushButton("click me to check")
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda : self.findText(self.lineEdit.text()))

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label,       0, 0, 1, 2)  
        self.grid.addWidget(self.chBox,       1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit,    1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textBrowser, 2, 0, 1, 2)   
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button,      3, 0, 1, 2)

    def findText(self, text=None):
        if self.lineEdit.hasAcceptableInput():
            self.textBrowser.append(text)      
            if self.chBox.isChecked():  
                self.textBrowser.insertPlainText("; chBox -> True. Is this a gift item.")        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = Demo()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: The pop-up window gets created. However, it pops-up in the background (behind the current window). It has to pop up in front so that the user know it has popped up. Also, the cursor should be on the input field so that the user can paste the order number (that is what the users will mostly do in my case, they will not type the number, they will just paste the copied number). Also, after they enter the number, & check whether it is a gift item or not, there should be only OK & Cancel button. Once they give the numebr according to format & click OK, the pup-up window should go away.